# Simplifying a cubefile parser

Tags: pyparsing

I am trying to parse [cubefiles](https://h5cube-spec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cubeformat.html#field-layout), *i.e.* something like this:

```
Cube file format
Generated by MRChem
 1  -1.500000e+01  -1.500000e+01  -1.500000e+01   1
10   3.333333e+00   0.000000e+00   0.000000e+00
10   0.000000e+00   3.333333e+00   0.000000e+00
10   0.000000e+00   0.000000e+00   3.333333e+00
 2   2.000000e+00   0.000000e+00   0.000000e+00   0.000000e+00
4.9345e-14  3.5148e-13  1.5150e-12  3.8095e-12  6.1568e-12  6.1568e-12
3.8095e-12  1.5150e-12  3.5148e-13  4.9344e-14  3.5148e-13  2.3779e-12
1.0450e-11  3.0272e-11  5.4810e-11  5.4810e-11  3.0272e-11  1.0450e-11
```

My current parser is as follows:

```py
import pyparsing as pp


# define simplest bits
int_t = pp.pyparsing_common.signed_integer
float_t = pp.pyparsing_common.sci_real
str_t = pp.Word(pp.alphanums)

# comments: the first two lines of the file
comment_t = pp.OneOrMore(str_t, stopOn=int_t)("comment")

# preamble: cube axes and molecular geometry
preamble_t = ((int_t + pp.OneOrMore(float_t) + int_t) \
+ (int_t + float_t + float_t + float_t) \
+ (int_t + float_t + float_t + float_t) \
+ (int_t + float_t + float_t + float_t) \
+ (int_t + float_t + float_t + float_t + float_t))("preamble")

# voxel data: volumetric data on cubic grid
voxel_t = pp.delimitedList(float_t, delim=pp.Empty())("voxels")

# the whole parser
cube_t = comment_t + preamble_t + voxel_t
```

The code above *does work*, but can it improved? Especially the definition of `preamble_t` seems to me like it could be done more elegantly. I have not been able to, though: my attempts thus far have only resulted in non-working parsers.

**UPDATE**

Following the answer and the further suggestion on rolling my own `countedArray`, this is what I have now:

```py
import pyparsing as pp


int_t = pp.pyparsing_common.signed_integer
nonzero_uint_t = pp.Word("123456789", pp.nums).setParseAction(pp.pyparsing_common.convertToInteger)
nonzero_int_t = pp.Word("+-123456789", pp.nums).setParseAction(lambda t: abs(int(t[0])))
float_t = pp.pyparsing_common.sci_real
str_t = pp.Word(pp.printables)

coords = pp.Group(float_t * 3)
axis_spec = pp.Group(int_t("nvoxels") + coords("vector"))
geom_field = pp.Group(int_t("atomic_number") + float_t("charge") + coords("position"))

def axis_spec_t(d):
    return pp.Group(nonzero_uint_t("n_voxels") + coords("vector"))(f"{d.upper()}AXIS")

geom_field_t = pp.Group(nonzero_uint_t("ATOMIC_NUMBER") + float_t("CHARGE") + coords("POSITION"))

before = pp.Group(float_t * 3)("ORIGIN") + pp.Optional(nonzero_uint_t, default=1)("NVAL") + axis_spec_t("x") + axis_spec_t("y") + axis_spec_t("z")
after = pp.Optional(pp.countedArray(pp.pyparsing_common.integer))("DSET_IDS").setParseAction(lambda t: t[0] if len(t) !=0 else t)


def preamble_t(pre, post):
    preamble_expr = pp.Forward()
    
    def count(s, l, t):
        n = t[0]
        preamble_expr << (n and (pre + pp.Group(pp.And([geom_field_t]*n))("GEOM") + post) or pp.Group(empty))
        return []
    
    natoms_expr = nonzero_int_t("NATOMS")
    natoms_expr.addParseAction(count, callDuringTry=True)
    
    return natoms_expr + preamble_expr

w_nval = ["""3   -5.744767   -5.744767   -5.744767    1
   80    0.143619    0.000000    0.000000
   80    0.000000    0.143619    0.000000
   80    0.000000    0.000000    0.143619
    8    8.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
    1    1.000000    0.000000    1.400000    1.100000
    1    1.000000    0.000000   -1.400000    1.100000
  2.21546E-05  2.47752E-05  2.76279E-05  3.07225E-05  3.40678E-05  3.76713E-05
  4.15391E-05  4.56756E-05  5.00834E-05  5.47629E-05  5.97121E-05  6.49267E-05
  7.03997E-05  7.61211E-05  8.20782E-05  8.82551E-05  9.46330E-05  1.01190E-04
  1.07900E-04  1.14736E-04  1.21667E-04  1.28660E-04  1.35677E-04  1.42680E-04
  1.49629E-04  1.56482E-04  1.63195E-04  1.69724E-04  1.76025E-04  1.82053E-04
  1.87763E-04  1.93114E-04  1.98062E-04  2.02570E-04  2.06601E-04  2.10120E-04
""", """-3  -12.368781  -12.368781  -12.143417   92
   80    0.313134    0.000000    0.000000
   80    0.000000    0.313134    0.000000
   80    0.000000    0.000000    0.313134
    8    8.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.225363
    1    1.000000    0.000000    1.446453   -0.901454
    1    1.000000   -0.000000   -1.446453   -0.901454
   92    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19
   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29
   30   31   32   33   34   35   36   37   38   39
   40   41   42   43   44   45   46   47   48   49
   50   51   52   53   54   55   56   57   58   59
   60   61   62   63   64   65   66   67   68   69
   70   71   72   73   74   75   76   77   78   79
   80   81   82   83   84   85   86   87   88   89
   90   91   92
 -1.00968E-10 -3.12856E-09  3.43398E-09 -8.36581E-09 -3.70577E-14  9.20035E-07
 -3.78355E-06 -2.09418E-06 -9.41686E-13 -1.21366E-06 -4.87958E-06  3.50133E-06
 -5.61999E-07  3.54869E-18 -1.30008E-12 -9.48885E-07 -1.44839E-06 -1.68959E-06
 -3.21975E-06 -2.48399E-06 -5.12012E-07 -1.60147E-07 -9.88842E-13 -3.77732E-18
"""
]
for test in w_nval:
    res = preamble_t(before, after).parseString(test).asDict()
    print(f"{res=}")


wo_nval = ["""-3  -12.368781  -12.368781  -12.143417
   80    0.313134    0.000000    0.000000
   80    0.000000    0.313134    0.000000
   80    0.000000    0.000000    0.313134
    8    8.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.225363
    1    1.000000    0.000000    1.446453   -0.901454
    1    1.000000   -0.000000   -1.446453   -0.901454
   92    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19
   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29
   30   31   32   33   34   35   36   37   38   39
   40   41   42   43   44   45   46   47   48   49
   50   51   52   53   54   55   56   57   58   59
   60   61   62   63   64   65   66   67   68   69
   70   71   72   73   74   75   76   77   78   79
   80   81   82   83   84   85   86   87   88   89
   90   91   92
 -1.00968E-10 -3.12856E-09  3.43398E-09 -8.36581E-09 -3.70577E-14  9.20035E-07
 -3.78355E-06 -2.09418E-06 -9.41686E-13 -1.21366E-06 -4.87958E-06  3.50133E-06
 -5.61999E-07  3.54869E-18 -1.30008E-12 -9.48885E-07 -1.44839E-06 -1.68959E-06
 -3.21975E-06 -2.48399E-06 -5.12012E-07 -1.60147E-07 -9.88842E-13 -3.77732E-18
""",
"""3   -5.744767   -5.744767   -5.744767
   80    0.143619    0.000000    0.000000
   80    0.000000    0.143619    0.000000
   80    0.000000    0.000000    0.143619
    8    8.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
    1    1.000000    0.000000    1.400000    1.100000
    1    1.000000    0.000000   -1.400000    1.100000
  2.21546E-05  2.47752E-05  2.76279E-05  3.07225E-05  3.40678E-05  3.76713E-05
  4.15391E-05  4.56756E-05  5.00834E-05  5.47629E-05  5.97121E-05  6.49267E-05
  7.03997E-05  7.61211E-05  8.20782E-05  8.82551E-05  9.46330E-05  1.01190E-04
  1.07900E-04  1.14736E-04  1.21667E-04  1.28660E-04  1.35677E-04  1.42680E-04
  1.49629E-04  1.56482E-04  1.63195E-04  1.69724E-04  1.76025E-04  1.82053E-04
  1.87763E-04  1.93114E-04  1.98062E-04  2.02570E-04  2.06601E-04  2.10120E-04
"""]

for test in wo_nval:
    res = preamble_t(before, after).parseString(test).asDict()
    print(f"{res=}")
```

This works for the `w_nval` test cases (where the `NVAL` token is present) This token is, however, optional: the parsing of the `wo_nval` test cases fails, even though I am using the `Optional` token. Furthermore, the `NATOMS` token is not saved to the final dictionary. Is there a way to also save the counter in the `countedArray` implementation?

**UPDATE 2**

This is the final, working parser:

```py
import pyparsing as pp


# non-zero unsigned integer
nonzero_uint_t = pp.Word("123456789", pp.nums).setParseAction(pp.pyparsing_common.convertToInteger)
# non-zero signed integer
nonzero_int_t = pp.Word("+-123456789", pp.nums).setParseAction(lambda t: abs(int(t[0])))
# floating point numbers, can be in scientific notation
float_t = pp.pyparsing_common.sci_real

# NVAL token
nval_t = pp.Optional(~pp.LineEnd() + nonzero_uint_t, default=1)("NVAL")

# Cartesian coordinates
# it could be alternatively defined as: coords = pp.Group(float_t("x") + float_t("y") + float_t("z"))
coords = pp.Group(float_t * 3)

# row with molecular geometry
geom_field_t = pp.Group(nonzero_uint_t("ATOMIC_NUMBER") + float_t("CHARGE") + coords("POSITION"))

# volumetric data
voxel_t = pp.delimitedList(float_t, delim=pp.Empty())("DATA")


# specification of cube axes
def axis_spec_t(d):
    return pp.Group(nonzero_uint_t("NVOXELS") + coords("VECTOR"))(f"{d.upper()}AXIS")

before_t = pp.Group(float_t * 3)("ORIGIN") + nval_t + axis_spec_t("X") + axis_spec_t("Y") + axis_spec_t("Z")
# the parse action flattens the list
after_t = pp.Optional(pp.countedArray(pp.pyparsing_common.integer))("DSET_IDS").setParseAction(lambda t: t[0] if len(t) != 0 else t)


def preamble_t(pre, post):
    expr = pp.Forward()
    
    def count(s, l, t):
        n = t[0]
        expr << (geom_field_t * n)("GEOM")
        return n
    
    natoms_t = nonzero_int_t("NATOMS")
    natoms_t.addParseAction(count, callDuringTry=True)
    
    return natoms_t + pre + expr + post

cube_t = preamble_t(before_t, after_t) + voxel_t
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, you are very fortunate to have such a clear reference of the format for this data. Usually this kind of documentation is left to guesswork and experimentation.

Since you have a good definition of the layout, I would define some more groups, and results names:

```
# define some common field groups
coords = pp.Group(float_t * 3)
# or coords = pp.Group(float_t("x") + float_t("y") + float_t("z"))
axis_spec = pp.Group(int_t("nvoxels") + coords("vector"))
geom_field = pp.Group(int_t("atomic_number") + float_t("charge") + coords("position"))
```

Then use them to define preamble and give it some more structure:

```
preamble_t = pp.Group(
    int_t("natoms")
    + coords("origin") 
    + int_t("nval")
    + axis_spec("x_axis")
    + axis_spec("y_axis")
    + axis_spec("z_axis")
    + geom_field("geom")
)("preamble")
```

Now you can access the individual fields by name:

```
print(cube_t.parseString(sample).dump())

['Cube', 'file', 'format', 'Generated', 'by', 'MRChem', [1, [-15.0, -15.0, -15.0], 1, [10, [3.333333, 0.0, 0.0]], [10, [0.0, 3.333333, 0.0]], [10, [0.0, 0.0, 3.333333]], [2, 2.0, [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]], 4.9345e-14, 3.5148e-13, 1.515e-12, 3.8095e-12, 6.1568e-12, 6.1568e-12, 3.8095e-12, 1.515e-12, 3.5148e-13, 4.9344e-14, 3.5148e-13, 2.3779e-12, 1.045e-11, 3.0272e-11, 5.481e-11, 5.481e-11, 3.0272e-11, 1.045e-11]
- comment: ['Cube', 'file', 'format', 'Generated', 'by', 'MRChem']
- preamble: [1, [-15.0, -15.0, -15.0], 1, [10, [3.333333, 0.0, 0.0]], [10, [0.0, 3.333333, 0.0]], [10, [0.0, 0.0, 3.333333]], [2, 2.0, [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]]
  - geom: [2, 2.0, [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
    - atomic_number: 2
    - charge: 2.0
    - position: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
  - natoms: 1
  - nval: 1
  - origin: [-15.0, -15.0, -15.0]
  - x_axis: [10, [3.333333, 0.0, 0.0]]
    - nvoxels: 10
    - vector: [3.333333, 0.0, 0.0]
  - y_axis: [10, [0.0, 3.333333, 0.0]]
    - nvoxels: 10
    - vector: [0.0, 3.333333, 0.0]
  - z_axis: [10, [0.0, 0.0, 3.333333]]
    - nvoxels: 10
    - vector: [0.0, 0.0, 3.333333]
- voxels: [4.9345e-14, 3.5148e-13, 1.515e-12, 3.8095e-12, 6.1568e-12, 6.1568e-12, 3.8095e-12, 1.515e-12, 3.5148e-13, 4.9344e-14, 3.5148e-13, 2.3779e-12, 1.045e-11, 3.0272e-11, 5.481e-11, 5.481e-11, 3.0272e-11, 1.045e-11]
```

Extra credit: I see that the `GEOM` field should actually be repeated `NATOMS` times. Look at the code for `countedArray` to see how to make a self-modifying parser so that you can parse `NATOMS x GEOM` fields.

Comment: That's great! Much cleaner than my first attempt. I have looked at `countedArray`, as you suggested, but there's still some sharp edges: 

1. The number of atoms in the modified `countedArray` is not saved in the final dictionary. I can't quite figure out how to achieve that.
2. The `NVAL` token is optional, with a default value of 1. I have tried using `Optional`, without much luck though.

I have updated the question with my updated code and test samples.

Comment: You'll need to look past the specifics of `countedArray`, and follow the logic in it. Define the part that will vary in length as a `Forward()`, and then in the parse action for the count field, insert `count*expr` into that `Forward()`. Since 1 is the default if the count is missing, you can insert `expr` into the `Forward()` after creating it.

Comment: If `nval` is Optional, you have to be careful not to accidentally read the first int of the following line in its place ("80" in your examples). Use a negative lookahead like `pp.Optional(~pp.LineEnd() + int_t, default=1)` so that you won't read past the line end to get the nval.

Comment: Thanks for the help! All is working now and I have posted the complete final code.